# negative semidefinite matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, dynamical-systems, matrix-equations, control-theory, semidefinite-programming

Can someone point me to a paper, or show here, why symmetric matrices have orthogonal eigenvectors? In particular, I'd like to see proof that for a symmetric matrix $A$ there exists decomposition $A = Q\Lambda Q^{-1} = Q\Lambda Q^{T}$ where $\Lambda$ is diagonal.

Comment: Are $Q$ and $F$ real or complex matrices (and in the complex case shouldn't the transposes be a Hermitian transpose?)? And in your first equation are all sings correct and should there maybe be a (Hermitian) transpose on one of the two $L$?

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen $Q$ and $F$ are real. You are right, it should've been $LL^T$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the matrix $P$ is only required to be symmetric for $\star$ and the statement you want to show and nonnegative definite is the same a [positive semi-definite](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1576062/76466). So using $P'=-P$ would still qualify as symmetric, so substituting this into $\star$ yields

$$
Q^\top (P'\,F + F^\top P')\,Q = -Q^\top (P\,F + F^\top P)\,Q \preceq 0, \tag{$\times$}
$$

with $A \preceq 0$ indicating that $A$ is negative semi-definite. Note that this does not mean that $P'\,F + F^\top P' \preceq 0$. Namely, it could be that that resulting matrix is indefinite, however the positive semi-definite "contribution" to that matrix would lie in the null space/Kernel of $Q$. Namely, in general an indefinite symmetric real matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ has the [following eigendecomposition](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/82471/76466)

$$
A =
\begin{bmatrix}
V & U
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\Omega & 0 \\ 0 & \Phi
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
V^\top \\ U^\top
\end{bmatrix} = V\,\Omega\,V^\top + U\,\Phi\,U^\top,
$$

with $\Omega\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times m}\preceq0$ and $\Phi\in\mathbb{R}^{k\times k}\succeq0$ diagonal matrices, $k+m=n$, $V\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ and $U\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times k}$, such that $\begin{bmatrix}V&U\end{bmatrix}$ is a orthonormal matrix. Note that $X=V\,\Omega\,V^\top\preceq0$ and $Y=U\,\Phi\,U^\top\succeq0$. However, in order for $\times$ to be true and because the eigenvectors are orthogonal it should hold that $Q^\top Y\,Q =0$. Such that the LHS of $\times$ can also be written as

$$
Q^\top (P'\,F + F^\top P')\,Q = Q^\top X\,Q\preceq 0,
$$

since if $Q^\top Y\,Q \neq0$ then $\times$ would also be indefinite.

The difference between $\star$ and your statement is the additional term $Q^\top L\,L^\top Q$. That additional term can be shown to be positive semi-definite. And thus there should exists a $L$ such that

$$
Q^\top L\,L^\top Q = -Q^\top (P'\,F + F^\top P')\,Q. \tag{$\circ$}
$$

One such solution could be found by solving $L\,L^\top = -X \succeq 0$, with $X$ as defined previously; for example using the [Cholesky decomposition](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition). Moving all terms of $\circ$ to one side and factoring out $Q$ yields your statement

$$
Q^\top (P'\,F + F^\top P' + L\,L^\top)\,Q = 0,
$$

thus showing that it is equivalent to $\star$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification! I don't follow clearly why $X \preceq 0$, $Y \succeq 0$ and $Q^\top Y\,Q=0$ should hold. Any hint?

Comment: Also following your first equation, shouldn't the RHS of $\circ$ be positive?

Comment: @Morcus The RHS of $\circ$ has a negative sign in front. So using the first equation from my answer and negating it yields that the RHS of $\circ$ is positive semi-definite.

Comment: @Morcus Regarding your first comment, I only introduced $X$ and $Y$ to hopefully clarify without having to add too much details. But note that in general adding a positive semi-definite and a negative semi-definite matrix does not guarantee that its sum is indefinite. I will add a more detailed explanation using the eigendecomposition to my answer about why this can be done.

Comment: @Morcus I have updated my answer. Is it now clear or do you still have questions?

Comment: I appreciate the clear explanation! Thank you.